# How to disable default Callout view from mapkit?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I need to disable default callout view from map kit, I'm using customised callout view and now Its getting both view when i click on the pin icon.

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView){
    let customView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil))[0] as! CustomCalloutView;

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50))
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPressed:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    customView.addSubview(button) // assuming you're in a view controller

    self.view.addSubview(customView)
}
```

Comment: Try to add this line: customView!.canShowCallout = false

Comment: I have already did that,, it works only for first  time

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got solution.

just comment out the "Title" and "Description" from MKAnnotation object custom class.

Comment: This will pass an assumption to `MKMapKit` that the user is requesting no callout. This disables delegate calls to the respective annotation you touch.